# Does tcl free up memory of existing dict variable when new blank dict is assigned?

Tags: dictionary, tcl

My tcl application uses dictionary to store large databases and has to ensure memory does not blow up significantly. I am looking for a simple approach to free up memory of entire dictionary.

In the below code sequence, I am reassigning a blank dict to a variable which already has a large size dict associated with it. I can see that the contents of the new dict with the variable are empty but will it also free up the memory? in other words, is this equivalent to executing unset statement for key-value pairs?

```
set db [dict create]
dict set db key1 value1
dict set db key2 value2

# Will this next step recover memory of all previous key-value assignments?
set db [dict create]
```

Comment: Afaik, Tcl does not return memory to the operating system, but the memory used for the dictionary will be reused.

Comment: Would in that case the code above would tell Tcl that memory occupied earlier is free for other other variables to use? In other words, Tcl would not end up pulling more memory from OS while it has some already available.

Comment: @MadhurKashyap You can prove it by running your code in a loop and looking in the OS memory monitor. Overall memory usage will be constant, so from the OS's perspective there's obviously no extra memory used and therefore the memory _must_ be reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background Info:** Tcl's language model is that every value is a string. Strictly, at the implementation level every value is formally a *subtype* of string and values are passed by reference, with the references being immutable (and hence copied when they are written to) *if they are shared.* Unshared values are writable, though Tcl's got a *very* strict interpretation of that internally and the details are typically hidden entirely from scripts; you're not supposed to think of this stuff until you are dealing with optimising performance and even then not much.

So…

**Consequences:** The memory used to implement a dictionary is reclaimed automatically when the last reference to that dictionary goes away. This is identical to as in lists or large strings. (Well, small strings and numbers too, but they're usually not a Big Deal.)

So, if I do this:

```
set db [dict create big "bigger" biggest "even more"]
set db2 $db
unset db
```

then the memory is still allocated as the `db2` variable is holding a reference. Replacing `unset db` with `set db {}` or `set db [dict create]` will have pretty much the same effect; that original dictionary is still hanging around. However, once the *last* reference to it goes away (which could be even from inside another dictionary or list) then the memory is tidied up.

So yes, in your exact example, the memory is freed. We can prove this by running this loop:

```
while true {
    set db [dict create]
    dict set db key1 value1
    dict set db key2 value2
    set db [dict create]
}
```

and seeing that the OS thinks that the memory usage for the process is static even if the CPU usage is (close to) 100% of a CPU core. If it leaked memory, you *would* see it! (You can confirm that this is a reasonable test by adding an `lappend save $db` in that loop and seeing that memory usage grows fast. You'll want to kill that process fairly quickly once you've seen that it indeed is a memory hog of the worst kind…)

Comment: Tcl doesn't return the memory to the OS usually, but that's usually not a big deal in practice; most well-behaved processes have a limited maximum amount of memory they require, and the OS can manage it just fine using paging if required.

Comment: Tcl uses malloc()/free() for object allocation. It depends on the OS whether the OS 'sees' freed memory. If you want an in-depth analysis of Tcl memory usage, compile the Tcl library with TCL_MEM_DEBUG set which enables the 'memory' command (see man 3tcl memory).